# How to assign number data type to new column using SQL SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

I am generating a query table using SQL SELECT as below. This formats the numbers in the column 'Free Cashflow (USD mm)' with 2 digits, but the resulting column data type is 'text'.

How can I instead assign a number data type, e.g. 'float' with 2 digits, to the new column 'Free Cashflow (USD mm)' ?

```
SELECT
     (format(("fcf" / "fxusd") / 1000000, 2) as 'Free Cashflow (USD mm)'
FROM  "SF1"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `CAST` it to `DECIMAL`. Note that for values >= 1000, `FORMAT` will insert a `,` in the result, which will prevent the `CAST` from working correctly. Since `FORMAT` effectively just `ROUND`s the value to the given number of decimal places, you can use `ROUND` instead to resolve that problem:

```
SELECT
     CAST(ROUND(("fcf" / "fxusd") / 1000000, 2) AS DECIMAL(9,2)) as 'Free Cashflow (USD mm)'
FROM  "SF1"
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=af48b229dfb89ec41e6f0e2ebb0e5622)

Comment: Nick, I have a follow-up question with regard to my question and your answer above:  a row of the 'SF1' table columns `revenueusd` has a value of `261612000000`. The line `CAST(format("revenueusd" / 1000000, 2) AS DECIMAL (6, 2)) as 'Revenue (USD mm)'` converts it into a number column as intended, but the result is `261`. How can I generate the correct value and format of `261,612.00`?

Comment: @F.Marks there's a couple of issues. Firstly, `FORMAT` puts a `,` into the number when it is over 1000. Secondly the width of the field isn't wide enough. Since you want to keep the value as a number anyway, the solution is to just `ROUND` it instead. See my edit.

Comment: @F.Marks no worries. It's good you found the end case so the answer could be corrected in case other people see it in the future.